# Excel SQL Table Formula's clearing

Tags: sql, excel

Apologies if asked elsewhere, having checked couldn't find anything. I've got a SQL driven table in Excel. When my table refreshes, resulting in no data, it completely clears out a series of none-SQL driven columns on the far right of the table. Is there any way at all I can force Excel to store the formula on the cell, regardless of whether the row has cleared?

Comment: When the sql table does then have values, do you find that the formulas re-appear? They can look like they have vanished when no results are brought back in the SQL, but the formula is assigned to the column and reappear if the query then returns values later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ellaborate on my comment:

Below shows a simple query returning 10 dates from a database. The right column is a simple formula in excel adding 10 to the date:

[image]

If I update the query to return the top 0, you find the formula disappears because there are no values to assign the formula to:

[image]

But, I then update the query to bring back the original 10 dates again, and hey-presto, the formula re-appears!:

[image]

So I wouldn't think that you need to worry that it has gone. I would expect that they would come back once you return some values from your query.

FYI - More help on calculated columns can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-calculated-columns-in-an-Excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8) from Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I think I had 'preserve column sort/filter/layout' unticked - which was causing the formula to be lost when the data refreshed! Schoolboy error, thanks again